# absolute url for img src in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to print the absolute URLs of images in a browser window (i.e. 'www.mysite.com/hello/mypic.jpg'). This is a small snippet of my code:

```
$('img').each(function() {
        var pageInfo = {};

        var img_src = $(this).attr('src');

        alert(img_src);
});
```

My alerts keep printing the relative URLs (i.e. '/hello/mypic.jpg'). I've searched the forum and tried using $(this).src, but the alerts just inform me that img_src is undefined. Does anyone know how to get the absolute URL?

Comment: yes, but don't use `alert()`, use `console.log(img_src)` and look at the dev tools console.

Comment: Thanks mplungjan! That was exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jquery, the following code should actually already be good enough:

```
$("img").each(function() {
  var src = this.src;
  console.log(src); // will be absolute based on the current domain
});
```

Comment: Yeah, as I commented :)

Comment: if your comment is an actual answer, it shouldn't have been a comment. Remember to post it as an answer instead (a million people answered this question pretty much at the same time)

Comment: Yes, but only you and I posted the simple and correct code

Comment: which is kind of worrying really =x

Answer (score 0):

try this by accessing the .src property directly on the `<img>`,

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var pageInfo = {};
    alert( $(this)[0].src ); // this will give your desired result
    alert(img_src);
});
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/hq53nbLg/8/)

Comment: Why use `$(this)[0].src` when `this.src` works just fine.  One should only use jQuery when it's actually better.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the src attribute of your img, because for me it's giving the full src for the following example:

```
<img src="www.mysite.com/hello/mypic.jpg"></img>

$('img').each(function() {
        var pageInfo = {};
        var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
        alert(img_src);
});
```

**[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/gphc47yw/)**

your img's src must be containing only /hello/mypic.jpg